# How to detect object changes between service and component

Tags: angular

I have an object `CurrentUser` with `IsLoggedIn` property. I initiate this object in a service (`account.service`) and I have two controllers with their respective services `NavBar.controller` with `NavBar.service` and `Login.controller` with`Login.service`.

The router is set and works properly. My problem is that when the user is authenticated in login controller the navbar is not updated until I refresh the page (it's still logic because has a copy of the object CurrentUser and still don't know that is changed). so my question is how to update the navbar when user is logged in. I have found many question on how to share object and detect changes between controllers but the problem here is how the controller get the object changes from the service?

Comment: Did you try to have a service that is shared between the two Controllers?

Comment: Please give a [mcve]